# bookmark action only works for bookmarking one card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have bunch of cards that contains different data like id, name and etc, which each one has a bookmark button inside its jsx that I have returned using `cards.map(...)`:

```
const cards = [
  {id: 1, name: "saleh"},
  {id: 2, name: "hadi"},
  {id: 3, name: "reza"},
  {id: 4, name: "mansour"},
  ...
];
```

for handling bookmark button click I have created this function:

```
function bookmarkCard(id) {
  const clickedCard = cards.find((card) => card.id === id);
  const remainingCards = cards.filter((card) => card.id !== id);
  dispatch(
    setCards(
      [clickedCard, ...remainingCards]
    )
  );
}
```

for example, whenever I clicked on the 3th card's bookmark button the updated cards would be:

```
const cards = [
  {id: 3, name: "reza"},
  {id: 1, name: "saleh"},
  {id: 2, name: "hadi"},
  {id: 4, name: "mansour"},
  ...
];
```

but **the problem is** after first click, the second click (for example, on the id 2) the result would be:

```
const cards = [
  {id: 2, name: "hadi"},
  {id: 1, name: "saleh"},
  {id: 3, name: "reza"},
  {id: 4, name: "mansour"},
  ...
];
```

but I want it to looks like:

```
const cards = [
  {id: 2, name: "hadi"},
  {id: 3, name: "reza"},
  {id: 1, name: "saleh"},
  {id: 4, name: "mansour"},
  ...
];
```

That is, in fact I am only able to bookmark one card..